# Image width in canvas isnt being displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have this canvas I'm drawing onto. And I want to make image to be placed in the left lower corner.

```
var canvasWidth = 800;
var canvasHeight = 600;

$("#gameCanvas").attr("width", canvasWidth);
$("#gameCanvas").attr("height", canvasHeight);

var canvas = $("#gameCanvas")[0].getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
image.src="you.png";

var player1X =0;
var imageHeight=image.height;
var player1Y = canvasHeight - imageHeight;

canvas.rect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
canvas.fillStyle="#5c7792";
canvas.fill();

$(image).load(function(){
    canvas.drawImage(image, player1X , player1Y);
    });
```

but the problem is that when I use variable `player1Y`, it results in image being displayed at coordinates (0, canvasHeight). Actually, it results in image not being shown. But when I write `canvas.drawImage(image, player1X, canvasHeight - image.height)` it works perfectly.

How do I make the variable to control the posiotion of image?

Here is JSfiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/u9Ehs/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/u9Ehs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the image hasn't fully loaded when you are setting imageHeight & player1Y.

Refactor your code to set all image related variables inside image.onload:

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/CSQGh/

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var player1X=0;
    var player1Y;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/ship.png";
    function start(){
        player1Y=canvas.height-img.height;  
        ctx.drawImage(img,player1X,player1Y);
    }


}; // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me... I end up with white screen... BUT there is one thing: I updated my code a bit for it to get an input. I updated the Fiddle

Comment: You didn't try to refactor your code with my answer in mind.  You are still trying to set image related variables before the image is fully loaded. Set all image related variables INSIDE the .onload callback.  Images load asynchronously, meaning the browser will immediately process code after .src and then "callback" the onload code after it has fully loaded the image.

Comment: my fault, sorry. I rewrote code as you did and it works. But now only one problem left. I cant move image on Y axis because apparently it cant get value of player1Y. Also, Fiddle is updated again.

Comment: *Declare* player1Y first outside the .onload.  Then *set* player1Y inside the onload.  I updated my demo to show how to use player1Y outside the onload. Cheers! ;-)

Comment: My code looks almost exactly as you wrote in fiddle, but somewhy it doesnt wants to work... Anyway, I'll try to find the answer by myself now, thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Oops! I had a typo: Use `player1Y=canvas.height-img.height` not `var player1Y=canvas.height-img.height`.  :-/

Comment: I also forgot to update the link of fiddle... i didnt know it changes the link... my fault... AND I wrote as you did, but it still doesnt work on Y...